Decorators not work after update to Angular 17
After upgrade from Angular 15 to Angular 17 have not working property decorators in angular libs. I read about decorators ts 5 and i understood that decorator property can't change value. But how call old code?
I turned off useDefineForClassFields, turned on experimentalDecorators in tsconfig.
My decorator is adapter that connects data from the parent application to the child.
EXAMPLE:
angular lib @some/some-module
export class CreditsComponent  implements OnInit {
  


  @Adapter('user$')
  public user$:  Observable<any>;



  @Adapter('account$')
  public account$:  Observable<any>;

 public ngOnInit() {

    
      this.user$ /*------------------ now undefined ----------*/
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(res => this.user = res);

      this.account$ /*------------------ now undefined ----------*/
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(res => this.account = res);


angular lib @some/some-module Adapter function
export function Adapter(field: string) {
    return function (target: Object, propertyKey: string) {
        DecoratorService.adapter$.pipe(
            filter((res: AdapterService) => {
                return !!res.getOptions()[field];
            }),
            take(1)
        ).subscribe(
            res => {
                    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
                        value: res.getOptions()[field], /*---------- NO CHANGING VALUE ------*/
                    });
            }
        );

    }
}


MAIN APPLICATION
import { AdapterService } from '@some/some-module';


export class AppComponent {

  public constructor(
      private adapterService: AdapterService
  ) {
  }

  public initAdapter() {
    this.adapterService.setOptions('user$', this.currentAccountService.user$);

this.adapterService.setOptions('user$', this.currentAccountService.user$);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('accountSub', this.currentAccountService.accountSub);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('account$', this.currentAccountService.account$);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('accountsList$', this.accounts$);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('switchModalSub', this.modalSwitcherService.switchModalSub);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('switchModal$', this.modalSwitcherService.switchModal$);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('depositsProduct$', this.depositsProduct$);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('deposits$', this.deposits$);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('depositsSettings$', this.config$);
    this.adapterService.setOptions('eventSwitcherService', this.eventSwitcherService);

MAIN tsconfig
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": false,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "es2020",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@business/*": [
        "src/app/*"
      ],
      "@business-test/*": [
        "src/test-data/mock/*"
      ],
      "file-saver-es": [
        "@types/file-saver"
      ]
    },
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }

}


angular lib  @some/some-module tsconfig
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "dictionary-employees": [
        "dist/dictionary-employees"
      ],
      "foreign-economic-activity": [
        "dist/foreign-economic-activity"
      ],
      "trading-module": [
        "dist/trading-module"
      ],
      "credits-module": [
        "dist/credits-module"
      ],
      "@abank/shared-module": [
//        "projects/shared-module/src/lib"
        "dist/shared-module"
      ]
    },
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "es2022",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "lib": [
      "es2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}


